# I didn't see my opportunity in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, controller

I modified my class with

:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')

When I launch my Visualforce page i didn't see records.

What can i do?

Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Your negative example does not have an Opportunity Id provided in the URL with the `id` parameter. That appears to be the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing opportunity id as `:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('OpportunityId')`  for opportunity lines and contact roles. But it should be  : `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')`

```
public class controllerTest {
public Opportunity opportunity {get; set;}
public List<OpportunityLineItem> oppLineItem {get; set;}
public list<OpportunityContactRole> contact {get; set;}
public decimal totalAmt {get; set;}
public controllerTest(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
    controller.setPageSize(2);
}

public controllerTest(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    this.opportunity = [SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId, AccountId
                        FROM Opportunity
                        WHERE Id =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')
                       ];
    
    this.oppLineItem = [SELECT OpportunityId, Name, Quantity, UnitPrice, TotalPrice
                        FROM OpportunityLineItem
                        WHERE OpportunityId =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')                          
                       ];
    Decimal oliTotalAmount = 0;               
    for(OpportunityLineItem oli : this.oppLineItem){
        oliTotalAmount += oli.TotalPrice;
    }
    this.totalAmt = oliTotalAmount;
    
    this.contact = [SELECT id, ContactId, Contact.Name, Contact.Phone, Contact.Email, IsPrimary, Contact.Account.Name
                    FROM OpportunityContactRole
                    WHERE OpportunityId =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')
                    AND IsPrimary = true
                   ];
}
}
```

Comment: i have error "List has no rows for assignment to SObject". i open my opportunity "Step" in browser and open VF page in browser but i have this error...

Comment: Are you previewing the vf page. If so you will face this error as opportunity id is null

Comment: can you say me please how i can do it not in prewiew?

Comment: As you might have added it as button or action. Just open an opportunity and click on that particular action or button. It will show you the pdf file

Comment: that's help, thank you